# $watchCollection not being triggered on object change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've been trying to figure out why watchCollection isn't not triggered on object change ?

```
.factory('Products', function($http, $timeout){

    function Products(data){

        if (data) {
            this.setData(data);
        };

    };

    Products.prototype = {

        selected: {},

        setData: function(data) {
            angular.extend(this, { categories: data });
        },

        load: function() {

            var scope = this;

            $http
                .get('products.php?option=get_categories')
                .success(function(data) {

                    scope.setData(data);

                });

        }

    };

    var instanceManager = {

        products: false,

        get: function(){

            if (!this.products){

                this.products = new Products();

                this.products.load();

            };

            return this.products;

        }

    };

    return instanceManager;

})
```

Here's the directive:

```
.directive("foo", function(Products){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

            scope.products = Products.get();

            scope.$watchCollection(scope.products, function(newValue, oldValue){

                if (newValue == oldValue) {
                    return;
                };

                console.log("Hello!");

            });

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you include the part of the view that uses the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correct try this:

`scope.$watchCollection('products', function(newValue, oldValue){`

instead of

`scope.$watchCollection(scope.products, function(newValue, oldValue){`

`$watchCollection` can take either a string (angular expression) which evaluates to an array or an object or a function which returns a value.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, there's a typo. The parameter should an expression in form of function or string.

```
scope.$watchCollection(function(){ return scope.products; }, function(newValue, oldValue){



});
```

Comment: where did you see this ??? offical doc : `$scope.names = ['igor', 'matias', 'misko', 'james'];
$scope.dataCount = 4;

$scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, oldNames) {
  $scope.dataCount = newNames.length;
});`